# recursive sequence such as $x_{n+2}-2*x_{n+1}+4*x_{n}=0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have the recursive sequence such as $x_{n+2}-2*x_{n+1}+4*x_{n}=0$

We are looking for some solutions in the form $x_n=A* \lambda^n $

The equation becomes $A* \lambda ^{n+2}-2A \lambda ^{n+1}+4* A\lambda ^n=0   
 \longrightarrow P( \lambda)=\lambda ^2 - 2\lambda +4=0\longrightarrow \lambda_ {1/2}=1 \pm i\sqrt3=2 (\frac{1}{2} \pm i\frac{\sqrt3}{2})=2 (\cos\frac{\pi}{3} \pm i\sin\frac{\pi}{3})$.

$x_n=A \lambda_1^n+B \lambda_2^n=A 2^n(\cos\frac{n\pi}{3} + i\sin\frac{n\pi}{3})+B2^n(\cos\frac{n\pi}{3} - i\sin\frac{n\pi}{3})=2^n (A+B)(\cos\frac{n\pi}{3} )+ 2^n (A-B)i\sin\frac{n\pi}{3}=2^n (C)(\cos\frac{n\pi}{3} )+ 2^n (D)i\sin\frac{n\pi}{3}   \forall C,D \in R$

I don't understand why in the solution in my book there is
$x_n=2^n (C)(\cos\frac{n\pi}{3} )+ 2^n (D)\sin\frac{n\pi}{3}   \forall C,D \in R$ without the $i$

Comment: Did you mean $1\pm\sqrt3\color{red}i$? and $\pm i\color{red}\sin\frac\pi3$?

Comment: @Tanner yes, indeed. I edited the text

Comment: I added a second correction in my comment above:  you wrote cos instead of sin in a few places

Comment: yes, both of them as you've written

Comment: nobody answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you do not say this explicitly, it seems that you want all $x_n \in \mathbb R$. Your ansatz $x_n = A\lambda^n$ produces non-real $\lambda_{1/2}$, and thus you must look for $A,B \in \mathbb C$ such that
$$x_n = A\lambda_1^n + B\lambda_2^n \in \mathbb R \tag{1}.$$
$A,B \in \mathbb R$ will definitely not do the job. Solving $(1)$ is equivalent to looking for $C,D \in \mathbb C$ such that for all $n$
$$2^nC\cos(\frac{n\pi}{3})+ 2^nDi\sin(\frac{n\pi}{3}) \in \mathbb R . \tag{2}$$
Write $C = c + i c', D = d + id'$. The imaginary part of $(2)$ is
$$2^nc'\cos(\frac{n\pi}{3}) + 2^nd \sin(\frac{n\pi}{3})$$
and must vanish for all $n$. This is only possible for $c' = d = 0$. Thus you get the solution
$$x_n = 2^nc\cos(\frac{n\pi}{3}) -2^nd'\sin(\frac{n\pi}{3})$$
with arbitrary $c,d' \in \mathbb R$. That is the same as in your book.

Comment: thank you for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

The sine term's coefficient needs to be real for $x_n$ to be real. If $x_n$ is allowed to be non-real complex, so are the coefficients.

Comment: but in this case $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are two complex numbers, why should $(\lambda_1)^n$ and  $(\lambda_2)^n$ shouldn't be complex numbers?

Comment: @Anne So for a real sequence $B=A^\ast$.

Comment: i don't understand A*

Comment: @Anne The conjugate of $A$, also denoted $\overline{A}$.

Comment: so what do you mean with B=A*. A and B are the constants in this case

Comment: @Anne Yes, but the choices of those constants that get a real sequence satisfy $B=A^\ast$.